# Custom `appbar` without using the `official appbar` or make the widgets stay still

Tags: flutter

I want the `scroll view widget (widget 3)` to scroll under the `news widget (widget 2)` & `widget 1`. I've seen `appbar` widget and I don't wanna use it. I want to create something which I can have more control of, like `custom appbar`, `without using the official appbar`. Is there a way to `keep my already made widgets 1 & 2 to stay as it is while the scroll view scrolls underneath?` I tried something like following  (for testing purposes) and it just `throws an overflow error` and `scroll view does not move at all`.

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
      children: <Widget>[
        Container(
          width: 100,
          height: 100,
          color: Colors.blue,
        ),
        SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                          
              children: <Widget>[
 Container(
          width: 100,
          height: 1000,
          color: Colors.blue,

]),),];
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Container(
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
              height: kToolbarHeight,
              color: Colors.redAccent,
              child: Stack(
                alignment: AlignmentDirectional.center,
                children: [
                  Text("LOGO"),
                  Positioned(
                      right: 16,
                      child: Icon(Icons.settings))
                ],
              ),
            ),
            Container(
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
              height: kToolbarHeight,
              color: Colors.purpleAccent,
              child: Stack(
                alignment: AlignmentDirectional.center,
                children: [
                  Text("NEWS"),
                  Positioned(
                      right: 16,
                      child: Row(
                        children: [
                          Icon(Icons.person),
                          SizedBox(width: 15,),
                          Icon(Icons.share),
                        ],
                      ))
                ],
              ),
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: Container(
                color: Colors.orange,
                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                child: SingleChildScrollView(
                  child: Column(
                    children: [
                      Container(
                        child: Text(
                          'This is a scrollview',style: TextStyle(fontSize: 60),
                        ),
                      ),
                      Container(
                        child: Text(
                          'This is a scrollview',style: TextStyle(fontSize: 60),
                        ),
                      ),
                      Container(
                        child: Text(
                          'This is a scrollview',style: TextStyle(fontSize: 60),
                        ),
                      ),
                      Container(
                        child: Text(
                          'This is a scrollview',style: TextStyle(fontSize: 60),
                        ),
                      ),
                      Container(
                        child: Text(
                          'This is a scrollview',style: TextStyle(fontSize: 60),
                        ),
                      ),


                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

I guess you want to do something like this. This can do its job.[image]

Answer (score 0):

you can use CustomScrollView:

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/CustomScrollView-class.html